# SQL Server 2008 nightly bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having some trouble getting a bulk insert to work properly. Currently I have 19 text files that are inserted into a table respective to the file name. I'm attempting to add one more. So, the text file is called `test1.txt`.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
USE db_name

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.test1

DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT db_name.dbo.test1
FROM ''F:\test\test1.txt''
WITH (      FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
            FIRSTROW =2,
            ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''')'
EXEC(@cmd)
```

So, the table is truncated leaving the headers and the field values are then added back with the new data. This works for all the other text files. Here is the catch. The data coming over has a Year and Month column. I'm using a data loading tool as part of my ETL process that requires an actual yyyy/mm/dd. So I use the following sql to take the Year and Month I'm given for any record, and force it to be the last day of that particular month (last day because that is when our aging transactions are recorded). Here is the sql that does this:

```
    SELECT  DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, -1, 
       CAST(
         CAST([ YEAR ] AS VARCHAR(4)) +
           RIGHT('0' + CAST([ MONTH ] AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
             RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
        AS DATE)), 0) -1 as TransDate
```

This works for my purpose. So if I get the following data 2015 | 08, it will turn that into 2015/08/31. Now here is the kicker. When I run the sql server import/export wizard and insert the test1.txt into a table, and then run that select statement, it works just fine. But using the above bulk insert will cause that select statement to return the following error after its finished  inserting:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I realize this may be confusing, but there are a lot of steps in the process I work with. If you have any questions or need clarification please let me know. Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the data in your aging table after the bulk insert, but before the select, and see if there are any values for Month & Year that couldn't be used to construct a valid date.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Phocas_Staging.dbo.aging WHERE ISDATE(CAST([ YEAR ] AS VARCHAR(4)) +
           RIGHT('0' + CAST([ MONTH ] AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
             RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)) != 1` to find the problem rows/data